# Не могу достать значение через getIntExtra

Tags: android

Я вызываю активность через:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputData_DialogActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("currently page", currentlyPage);
    startActivity(i);
```

А потом, во второй активности достаю `Extra` через:

```
    int currentlyPage = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("currently page", 0);
```

И в результате получаю значение 0 (хотя передаю 3, я проверял)!

---

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала в Bundle значения засунуть, потом бандл в интент.

Вытаскиват так:

```
Intent.getExtras().getInt("key", 0);
```

Comment: Убрал пробел — не помогло.

Comment: А как это сделать? О.о Кстати, строку передает даже с пробелом.

Comment: Bundle b = new Bundle(); b.putInt("key", value); i.putExrtas(b); Попробуйте не переменную передать а просто число, цифрами. У вас похоже очепятка где-то опять.

Comment: Имею в виду, что вы, видать, не уследили таки за значением переменной)

Comment: Сейчас попробую передать числом, чтобы найти "очепятку", а потом через `Bundle` попробую (хотя экономнее будет перевести строку в число...).

Comment: Дерзайте.....))

Comment: Я значение проверял за строку до передачи, так что все в порядке.

Comment: Оп! А число передается... :\

Comment: Вывожу в лог значение переменной, за строку до передачи и пишет 3, но передается 0! Что за мистика?О.о

Comment: А как из `Bundle` достать число? =)

Comment: Intent.getExtras().getInt("key", 0);

Comment: Работает! Добавьте в ответ. Но я, скорее всего, переведу переменную в строку (`Integer.toString`), а потом в число. Так меньше памяти будет потреблять (ведь минус одна переменная). Завтра, надеюсь, Вы будете тут :). Я буду думать, как выводить сотни строк из БД, а потом редактировать их — ошибки обеспечены. До конца каникул 4 дня, а до конца приложения еще писать и писать...

Comment: Вдобавил. Видать без гетЕкстрас поиск ключа хз где идет. Приводить типы туда сюда плохая практика. Прос

Comment: Почему "плохая практика"?

Comment: В какой-то момент чтонить пойдет неак и замучаетесь искать. Какой нить неразрывный невиимый пробел перед числом с сервера получите.. У меня такое было)

Comment: Один раз рискну (но больше не буду, честно :)). Сейчас еще один вопрос закину, минут через 20.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите this. тогда все должно сработать.